# How can I detect that a component has been freed?

Tags: delphi

I have a component that I create and then pass into it a panel on my main form.

Here is a very simplified example:

```
procedure TMy_Socket.StatusPanel_Add(AStatusPanel: TPanel);
```

This component will then update the panels caption as the need arises.

In my main program if I `FreeAndNil` the panel the next time the component tries to update the panel I get an AV.  I understand why: the component's reference to the panel now is pointing to an undefined location.

How can I detect within the component if the panel has been freed so I know I can not reference it?

I tried `if (AStatusPanel = nil)` but it is not `nil`, it still has an address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call the Panel's `FreeNotification()` method, and then have your `TMy_Socket` component override the virtual `Notification()` method, eg (given your naming scheme, I assume you can add multiple `TPanel` controls to your component):

```
type
  TMy_Socket = class(TWhatever)
  ...
  protected
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  ...
  public
    procedure StatusPanel_Add(AStatusPanel: TPanel); 
    procedure StatusPanel_Remove(AStatusPanel: TPanel); 
  ...
  end;

procedure TMy_Socket.StatusPanel_Add(AStatusPanel: TPanel); 
begin
  // store AStatusPanel as needed...
  AStatusPanel.FreeNotification(Self);
end;

procedure TMy_Socket.StatusPanel_Remove(AStatusPanel: TPanel); 
begin
  // remove AStatusPanel as needed...
  AStatusPanel.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
end;

procedure TMy_Socket.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (AComponent is TPanel) and (Operation = opRemove) then
  begin
    // remove TPanel(AComponent) as needed...
  end;
end;
```

If you are only tracking one `TPanel` at a time instead:

```
type
  TMy_Socket = class(TWhatever)
  ...
  protected
    FStatusPanel: TPanel;
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  ...
  public
    procedure StatusPanel_Add(AStatusPanel: TPanel); 
  ...
  end;

procedure TMy_Socket.StatusPanel_Add(AStatusPanel: TPanel); 
begin
  if (AStatusPanel <> nil) and (FStatusPanel <> AStatusPanel) then
  begin
    if FStatusPanel <> nil then FStatusPanel.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
    FStatusPanel := AStatusPanel;
    FStatusPanel.FreeNotification(Self);
  end;
end;

procedure TMy_Socket.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (AComponent = FStatusPanel) and (Operation = opRemove) then
    FStatusPanel := nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

If your component needs to be notified when another component is freed, have a look at [`TComponent.FreeNotification`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_FreeNotification.html).  It should be just what you need.

Comment: @Steve: You put the Notification proc on your `TMy_Socket` class.  Check out the example at the bottom of the documentation page.