# How to check an object is released in firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, object, firemonkey

I create a component and use it at another place,but I don't know if the component was released.

So how to check an object is released before use it?

Thanks.

Comment: For `TComponent` descendants solution would be using `FreeNotification`. If there is only one reference to the object then reseting reference back to `nil` after release is another method.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve, as well as are you targeting mobile, desktop compilers or both.

Comment: Maybe this covers what you need [How can I detect that a component has been freed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12499722/4267244)

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you are targeting the mobile compilers, because otherwise ARC is not in use and the question then seems to be meaningless.

Test the [`Disposed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.Disposed) property.

> Disposed is a read-only property that shows the current state of this
>   object.
>
> The Disposed property returns True if the object has been disposed
>   using the DisposeOf method. Otherwise, it returns False.

However, that you might even ask this question does seem odd. Perhaps you are not solving your problem in the best possible way.

Comment: What's the downvote for? I'm quite prepared to have made a mistake.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thanks. I was assuming mobile compilers, and have now stated that. I agree that this smells bad.

Comment: Using `Disposed` property for anything beyond temporary debug tool is really, really bad coding practice. If there is need to check if object is released with `Disposed` then code has to be changed in a way that would not need such checks.

Comment: @Dalija I agree. I said as much.

Comment: I feel so strongly against using `Disposed` that I felt the need to make it more obvious than your answer shows. Especially, since it question looks more like "how to do this" than "how to debug my code".

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That's fine. I appreciate your contributions.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly appreciate your contributions :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading your other question it seems you're trying to debug a memory issue on OSX and you're trying to find out which object has been freed but is still being used.

I'd recommend using FastMM4 with Full Debug mode turned on. Don't forget to deploy libFastMM_FullDebugMode.dylib with your project for debugging with FastMM4. This will raise an exception if you're trying to access an object that has been freed.

Answer (score 0):

a reference to the class is "alive" until you clear all references to it.
if you don't use dirty methods like DisposeOf, or use a weak ref.

The best way - to use a TDictionary.
Add the address of a class in the constructor, and delete it in the destructor.